# Why does my webkit transform CSS not work as expected?

Tags: jquery, css, webkit, css-transforms

I have a page that you can view/download from  http://dl.dropbox.com/u/16178847/eyewitness/a/b.html, but I am unable to figure out exactly how to do what I am trying to do. What I want is a card flipping effect, and on one side, the ability to click in order to show/hide a header and footer. You will probably need a webkit browser for it to work.

I have the header and footer show/hide working: click anywhere on the photo (or it's containing div) to show/hide the header/footer.

I even have most of the flip working: click the info icon, and the back icon/words. What I'm struggling with is making the image dissapear when flipped, and getting the back side (which is currently below the front side) actually in the same place as the front side so it really looks like a card flipping.

You will see in my css that I have commented out two lines. They are what I expect to have to use, but aren't working. The first one on .face makes the image and footer disappear, and the second one on .photo does nothing. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this tutorial should help: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/all/

You may also need to use jquery to add/remove some classes.

Comment: Thanks. I am currently reading this and still struggling. I'll have another go soon. If it leads to me solving my issue I will accept your answer.

Comment: Well I started from scratch (again) after reading that article, and got it working. Not sure what the difference was, and because I started from scratch there are so many changes to compare that it wasn't worth doing. Thanks for pointing me in the direction of this article.